# Hadoop MiniCluster Web UI

Tags: web, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Does the hadoop Minicluster supports web UI..?If yes how to access the web UI in Minicluster setup

[image]

Facing Forbidden error while trying to load web UI.Using Hadoop Version 2.10.2 Maven